# Set textbox focus in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-safari

Hey, I was wondering how to set the focus to a text box in Mobile Safari.

I've tried `document.myForm.myTextArea.focus()` which works in regular Safari, but it does not seem to work in Mobile Safari.

To clarify, I want to set focus to a text box as soon as the user loads a page, and have the iPhone keyboard pop up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found this previous post stating this is a bug in webkit. Sorry for not doing a more thorough search.

http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?t=127724

Comment: Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

Answer (score 4):

I found a bug report with the iUI project relating to this.

It seems that a `focus()` call will not work if called from the `onload` event or if called via a timer.

http://code.google.com/p/iui/issues/detail?id=129

**Update:** Although I have no source for this, I am told (by people who have tried it) that in iPhone OS 4 the problem with `focus()` and `onload` should be fixed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case in iOS 4... Can others confirm?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists in iOS 4.

Comment: Problem is still here in iOS 4.3.2

Comment: Some frameworks, e.g. SproutCore, use a setTimeout based run-loop, within which focus() don't work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with the timer, focus() doesnt work at all... im doing mine through an AJAX function. i guess my web application will have to suffer in mobile safari.

Bye the way, this also affects HP webOS devices and any other device using mobile safari