# Is it possible to invoke the Keyboard on an input or textarea using Javascript in Mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I had hoped that

```
$("#element").focus();
```

or

```
$("#element").click();
```

Would work but no luck.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by invoke a keyboard?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398528/set-textbox-focus-in-mobile-safari

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari-iPhone-or-iPad-with-JavaScript-how-can-I-launch-the-on-screen-keyboard

Comment: Making the iOS on screen keyboard show using Javascript

Answer (score -2):

If `$("#element")` is an input or textarea field, then yes, this will cause the keyboard to appear. But only in those cases (not sure about `contenteditable` divs...).