# Sencha Touch: How to programmatically focus on a textfield on ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to do a pin login similar to those found on ios and android, where the user must enter a 4 digit pin to continue. The problem I am having is that I want the input to be selected and the numberpad to be shown as soon as the user enters the page, so that the user can just enter their password.

I checked their documentation and it shows that the textfield is focusable http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-event-focus but people have been having problems with it.

I am compiling my code using sencha CMD and converting it to a Native App. The focus works fine on android devices but it doesn't work on ios devices.

Below is a simple proof of concept:

```
Ext.application({
name : ('SF' || 'SenchaFiddle'),

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        fullscreen : true,
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'textfieldId'
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'click me to focus',
                handler: function () {
                    this.parent.down('#textfieldId').focus();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
});
```

Comment: I ve been strugglin with that particular issue, seems like mobile safari just doesnt support autofocus. There are some dicussions about the topic: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4710766?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS web views (since iOS 6) are designed to block text field autofocus by default since obtaining focus will also present the keyboard, apparently degrading the user experience. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_9) for more details. This affects Safari as well as web views in native applications.

If you're building a native application you can override this behavior. For example, if you're using Cordova or PhoneGap you can override this setting in your project's `MainViewController::webViewDidFinishLoad` method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Allow the keyboard to appear with Javascript focus events...
    theWebView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = false;

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

There are several other SO discussions that deal with this topic:

- [Mobile Safari Autofocus text field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6287478/814416)
- [Set textbox focus in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2398528/814416)

Answer (score 2):

I am using Touch 2.4 and was able to get the field to focus in the browser this way:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
label: 'Test Example',
name: 'testField',
listeners: [
    {
        fn: function(element, eOpts) {
            element.down('input').dom.focus();
        },
        event: 'painted'
    }
]
```

I will need to follow up with how this works when deployed to a device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...here the text box appears with a focus to enter digit..

```
<tpl  if="ItemKey==this.getChecked(values.ItemKey)">
                       <input  style="color:green;display:block;width:50px;text-align:center;" type="text"
                       id="{ItemKey}"
                       onkeyup="MyApp.app.getController(\'Control\').TextboxKeyUp(this)"
                       value={[this.getScore(values.ItemKey)]}
                        onfocus="MyApp.app.getController(\'Control\').patTextFocus(this)" ><tpl else>
```