# this script works on my desktop but not in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

```
dropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
   $('input#photo_title').focus();
});
```

is there some reason that this script does not work in Safari/iphone? It works just fine on my desktop.

Safari is up to date. i want to put the focus on the input with the mobile keyboard displayed and insert cursor displayed, instead the input is highlighted but must be clicked to bring the keyboard up/insert cursor up.

Comment: `does not work` - what do you expect? what do you observe instead?

Comment: Can you clarify "does not work"? Is there an error? Function does not get called? Other?

Comment: What version of safari? The site says Safari 6+, is that the case?

Comment: yes it is up to date. i want to put the focus on the input with the mobile keyboard displayed and insert cursor displayed, instead the input is highlighted but must be clicked to bring the keyboard up/insert cursor up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set textbox focus in mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398528/set-textbox-focus-in-mobile-safari)

it is not possible to use .focus() to bring up the keyboard in IOS. This is the design and from numerous web sources apparently there is nothing you can do about it.